# Authorize/Capture for PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, groupon

Using PayPal IPN, can we implement delayed payment. Perfect example is Groupon where card is charged only when deal is tipped. Can someone throw light on implementation part using PayPal IPN and also how multiple cards can be charged at once when deal is tipped.

Comment: didnt got your second requirement of charging multiple cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Authorize And Capture:

To make a payment authorize you will have to pass "authorization" in `paymentmethod` parameter instead of "sale"

```
  <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization" />
```

So, For this type of payment, paypal will not charge the sender immediately but will wait till receiver confirmation. To capture this payment two methods are available:

1. Receiver will either click on capture button in account
2. It can be done via a API - to capture the payment use [DoCapture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoCapture) and void the payment use [DoVoid](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoVoid)