# Paypal: Is there a way to check a cart right before a user pays?

Tags: paypal, authorization, payment

Is there any way currently for Paypal's API to send my site an authorization request before completing a user's payment?

I think the answer here would be that there is no way to do this, but one can set "authorization" as a cart parameter instead of "sale". This still leaves the question of how to complete the authorization in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would clarify your doubt up to a certain extent.

Authorization & Capture starts when your buyer authorizes a payment amount during checkout.

For example, you can use the PayPal Express Checkout API with the PAYMENTACTION element set to Authorization or Order.

After your buyer completes checkout, you can then use the payment’s transaction ID with Authorization & Capture APIs. You can:

- Capture either a partial amount or the full authorization amount.
- Authorize a higher amount, up to 115% of the originally authorized amount (not to exceed an increase of $75 USD).
- Void a previous authorization.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that you can specify an "authorization" or a "sale" via the payment method parameter: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305782/authorize-capture-for-paypal ... the answer to my original question would still be "no," wouldn't it?